# Text search in Solr where the field is the substring of the query

Tags: solr, full-text-search, text-search

I'm new to Solr and I'm not fully aware of what it can and can't do.

I'm trying to build a system where the documents will have a field with a string value `x`, and I want to efficiently query those documents against some string `y`, where `x` is a substring of `y`. It's like the opposite of the usual substring matching queries.

Is this possible to do efficiently in Solr? If not, does limiting `x` to be a single word and `y` to only consists of few words helps in anyway?

Comment: You should be able to do what you're looking for by using an ngramfilter inside your `query` analysis block in the field definition: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/filters.html#n-gram-filter - performance may wary, so test it out with real life query profiles.